# Ecto: run sql script before or after each migration

Tags: dynamic, migration, elixir, partitioning, ecto

I would like to create(if not exists) partition tables for each month for some time in the future:

```
execute """
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS #{table}_p#{start_date.year}_#{month}
PARTITION OF #{table} FOR VALUES
FROM ('#{start_date}')
TO ('#{stop_date}')
"""
```

I run it dynamically, eg: for next 12 month starting from today.
I would like to make it during migration, but run it each time migration starts. I can't use `Repo` since in time of the migration it's not yet started. I didn't find any ability to do it with [Ecto.Migration api](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto_sql/Ecto.Migration.html).

Do you have any ideas how to achieve this?

Comment: Could you put this into your own mix task and then create an alias inside of mix.exs so that running `mix ecto.migrate` instead ran your task first and then the `ecto.migrate`?  You may need to start the repo process yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it with support of feature added in [ecto 3.5.0](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto_sql/3.5.0/Ecto.Migrator.html#migrations_path/2). I added separate migration folder wich is used for so called 'repeated_migrations'.

```
  @doc """
  repeated migrations are run each deploy(e.g: ensure partitions). Repetition achieved by down method that does nothing.
  """
  def run_repeated_migrations do
    for repo <- repos() do
      path = Ecto.Migrator.migrations_path(repo, "repeated_migrations")
      {:ok, _, _} = Ecto.Migrator.with_repo(repo, &Ecto.Migrator.run(&1, path, :up, all: true))
      {:ok, _, _} = Ecto.Migrator.with_repo(repo, &Ecto.Migrator.run(&1, path, :down, all: true))
    end
  end
```

method in repeated_migrations/20210427134701_partition_creation.exs

```
  def down do
    # to make this migration repeatable we run 'up' following by 'down'. Down do nothing.
    execute "SELECT 1"
  end
```